# Can you run a Windows batch file in compatability mode

Tags: windows, batch-file

We run a Java application wrapped as an exe on Windows 7 in Windows XP Compatability mode to solve a performance problem. We also provide a batch file to run the same java application, is there any way to run the batch file using the same compatability mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just right click the batch file, open properties. In the compatibility tab, set the required compatibility.

Note: AFAIK, Compatibility settings are set in the Windows Registry. Hence if you move the batch file to a different machine, the settings have to be re-applied. Else you need to figure out the registry entries involved and add it to the other machine's registry.

Answer (score 4):

In command line or bat file:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=WINXPSP3
app_you_want_to_run_in_compatibility_mode.exe
```

Check also:

- http://www.nebev.net/blog/?p=54
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b04c780a-86bd-420d-9d44-86e00e7c51de/compatibility-mode-from-command-line-is-it-possible?forum=w7itproappcompat

Comment: the first link is dead, there is no clue how to search for it